# Cannot redeclare class but there are no other classes with that name

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I am working right now with `Zend Framework` and I've created a `Model_User_Row` in `app\models\User\Row.php`.

When I try to create an instance of that class in `IndexController` I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Model_User_Row in
F:\Projekty\www\inz\app\models\User\Row.php on line 14
```

14th line is a close brace.

```
<?php

class Model_User_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        $res = parent::toArray();
        unset($res['password']);
        return $res;
    }
} // #14
```

In my project I have no other class called `Model_User_Row`.

I am a bit confused - how to debug this case ?

Comment: Maybe the autoloader is doing something wrong and including the file twice?

Comment: I would search the entire codebase for "class Model_User_Row" just to be certain you have not duplicated the class' name. Also, are you including the class' definition manually at any point in your code either with an include/require or such, or is everything through Zend_Loader?

Comment: I've already searched. It was the first thing before asking here. ;) Everything is loaded with `Zend_Loader` - none of manually includes.

Comment: `@Pekka` - you were right - it was loaded before in `Zend_Loader`. Found it and it's solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Zend_Loader then you should check to make sure that it is configured/coded correctly and it is not attempting to load the class file multiple times then.